# working of NTLMv2 with LDAP

Tags: ntlmv2

I'm using NTLMv1 and its working fine. The only disdavantage is once if I logged in then its hitting LDAP server for 3 to 4 times.

So I don't want that. Can any one please explain me how this process is in NTLMv2?

below is the code for NTLMv2

```
          <filter>
            <filter-name>ntlmv2-auth</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.ntlmv2.filter.NtlmFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                    <!-- Windows domain name -->
                    <param-name>ntlm-domain</param-name>
                    <param-value>ACME.CORP</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <!-- IP-address of domain controller -->
                    <param-name>ntlm-dc</param-name>
                    <param-value>dcone.acme.com</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <!-- Simple (non-FQDN) hostname of DC host -->
                    <param-name>ntlm-dc-name</param-name>
                    <param-value>dcone</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <!-- Computer account for connection to DC -->
                    <param-name>ntlm-account</param-name>
                    <param-value>TECHUSER$@ACME.CORP</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <!-- Password of computer account -->
                    <param-name>ntlm-password</param-name>
                    <param-value>test1234</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>NTLMv2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot avoid the repeated LDAP connection, as the NTLM protocol is designed to do this exactly. You can find more information on the [Microsoft Page defining the NTLM Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc669093.aspx)